# Button items starts hiding when added in RibbonBar

Tags: wpf, dotnetbar

I have a fixed length RibbonBar such that in one row it can accomodate 3 ButtonItems. When I add 4th ButtonItem, instead of being added in the next row it gets added in the same first row and is not seen as it crosses the boundary of RibbonBar.

Im using DotNetBar for the first time. I found a property AutoOverFLowEnbled but it does not get the buttontem in the next line. Is there anyother property or something I'm missing?